# How can I tell eclipse to interpret the content within a script tag (text/ng-template) as a specific language?

Tags: html, angularjs, eclipse

As in:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="/my-template.html">
    <p>Test</p>
</script>
```

Currently, when I edit this in the HTML editor, it doesn't know that the contents of the script tag is actually HTML because it doesn't know what the text/ng-template content type is. I'd like to have all the features like colors and autocomplete of the HTML editor within those script tags so I don't have to keep taking them in and out. Is this possible?

Comment: like a plug-in to extend the IDE's functionality like this angularjs plug-in for Eclipse: [link](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/angularjs-eclipse) ? you may need to install the javascript development tools (JSDT) too, from here: [link](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/jsdt/)

Comment: This issue is known, see https://github.com/angelozerr/angularjs-eclipse/issues/148 but today I have not found a solution to fix it.